# Using Jsonseralizer when the value comes across with 'Null'

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have a json string I am trying to serialize into an object, but some of the values are 'null', not null as in empty, but actually the word null, unfortunately those are not string values.  I attempted to add the defaultignorecondition whenwritingnull, but that alone doesn't seem to work.  The error is:

*InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'Null' as a number*

My code:

```
 var settings = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull   
            };
gdata = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<gasData>>(response.Content, settings);
```

Example from the json raw data:

```
"no_offset":0.0000,"no_units":"ppb","so2_sensor_serial_number":null,"so2_state":"Not Fitted","so2_prescaled":null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it is working properly

```
var json = "{\"no_offset\":0,\"no_units\":\"ppb\",\"so2_sensor_serial_number\":null,\"so2_state\":\"Not Fitted\",\"so2_prescaled\":null}";

var data = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(json);
```

class

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonPropertyName("no_offset")]
    public long? NoOffset { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("no_units")]
    public string NoUnits { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("so2_sensor_serial_number")]
    public long? So2SensorSerialNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("so2_state")]
    public string So2State { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("so2_prescaled")]
    public object So2Prescaled { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Discussed here by .net team: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30795